# Splitting of Lie groups over codimension 1 subgroups

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, semidirect-product

The following is stated as Theorem 3.1(i) on p. 50f. in Onishchik/Vinberg, Lie groups and Lie algebras III:

Let $G$ be a connected real Lie groups. If there is a closed connected normal subgroup $G_1$ of codimension $1$ , then there exists a one-dimensional Lie subgroup $C$ of $G$ such that $G$ is the semidirect product of $C$ and $G_1$.

It is easy to see that if $G$ is abelian, then the statement is true.  It is also easy to see that $G_1$ needs to contain the commutator subgroup of $G$ and hence its closure.

Onishchik/Vinberg now claim that one can reduce the general statement to the abelian case by induction on the dimension of $G$. I don't see how this is supposed to work. Any hints?

Comment: In my opinion, the proof of this theorem somehow misses the important case when $G_1=[G,G]$. We should start with this case. And then already conduct induction on the dimension of the group $G$.